# Adding outputs of two layers in keras

Tags: python-2.7, deep-learning, keras, keras-layer

I have an issue that seems to have no straight forward solution in Keras.
My server runs on ubuntu 14.04, keras with backend tensorflow.

Here's the issue:

I have two input tenors of the shape: `Input(shape=(30,125,1))`, each of them is fed to a cascade of three layers below:

```
CNN1 = Conv2D(filters = 8, kernel_size = (1,64) , padding = "same" , activation = "relu" )
CNN2 = Conv2D(filters = 8, kernel_size = (8,1) , padding = "same" , activation = "relu" )
pool = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))
```

Each of the obtained output tensors for respective inputs is of shape `(None, 15, 62, 8)`. Now, I wish to add each of the `(15,62)` matrix for both inputs for each filter and get an output of dimension again `(None, 15, 62, 8)`.

I tried with the following lines of code using Lambda layer but it throws an error.

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers import Lambda

def myadd(x):
    increment = x[1]
    result = K.update_add(x[0], increment)
    return result

in_1 = Input(shape=(30,125,1))
in_1CNN1 = CNN1(in_1)
in_1CNN2 = CNN2(in_1CNN1)
in_1pool = pool(in_1CNN2)

in_2 = Input(shape=(30,125,1))
in_2CNN1 = CNN1(in_2)
in_2CNN2 = CNN2(in_2CNN1)
in_2pool = pool(in_2CNN2)

y1 =y1.astype(np.float32) # an input regression label array of shape (numsamples,1) loaded from a mat file

out1 = Lambda(myadd, output_shape=(None, 15, 62, 8))([in_1pool,in_2pool])
a= keras.layers.Flatten()(out1)

pre1 = Dense(1000, activation='sigmoid')(a)
pre2 =Dropout(0.2)(pre1)
predictions = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(pre2)

model = Model(inputs=[in_1,in_2], outputs=predictions)
model.compile(optimizer='sgd',loss='mean_squared_error')
model.fit([inputdata1,inputdata2], y1, epochs=20, validation_split=0.5)
#inputdata1, inputdata2 are arrays loaded from a mat file and are each of shape (5169, 30, 125, 1)
```

The error is highlighted below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "keras_workshop/keras_multipleinputs_multiple CNN.py", line 225, in <module>
    out1 = Lambda(myadd, output_shape=(None, 15, 62, 8))([in_1pool,in_2pool])
  File "/home/tharun/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 603, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/home/tharun/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/layers/core.py", line 651, in call
    return self.function(inputs, **arguments)
  File "keras_workshop/keras_multipleinputs_multiple CNN.py", line 75, in myadd
    result = K.update_add(x[0], increment)
  File "/home/tharun/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 958, in update_add
    return tf.assign_add(x, increment)
  File "/home/tharun/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/state_ops.py", line 245, in assign_add
    return ref.assign_add(value)
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'assign_add'
```

Comment: Yes, Add() method is working.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [`Add()` layer](https://keras.io/layers/merge/#add) or the [`add()` function](https://keras.io/layers/merge/#add_1) that Keras provides.

---

> ### Add
>
> ```
> keras.layers.Add()
> ```
>
> Layer that adds a list of inputs.
>
> It takes as input a list of tensors, all of the same shape, and returns a single tensor (also of the same shape).

---

> ### add
>
> ```
> keras.layers.add(inputs)
> ```
>
> Functional interface to the Add layer.
>
> #### Arguments
>
> **inputs**: A list of input tensors (at least 2).
>   ****kwargs**: Standard layer keyword arguments.
>
> #### Returns
>
> A tensor, the sum of the inputs.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the answer to include some of the documentation inside the post itself, and to change it from more of a comment-like response to something more like a full answer. When you hit 50 rep you'll be able to comment (see more on this [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173)), but until then, try to keep your solutions written out fully and you'll be able to comment in no time anyways. Keep up the good work!